Understanding the unsoundness of Rust type compile time eq / neq
I've been messing a lot with Rust type system, and I've always hit the same barrier, the fact that we can't tell if two types are the same at compile time. More precisely, the fact that two types are different.
It is easy to write type equality trait bounds:
trait IsSame<T> {}
impl<T> IsSame<T> for T {}
[...] where U: IsSame<T>

But I've been struggling for type inequality, and precisely to write something like:
trait Boolean {} // type level boolean
struct True;
impl Boolean for True {}
struct False;
impl Boolean for False {}

// the trait I want to implement
trait IsEq<T> {
    // for <T as IsEq<T>> this is `True`, otherwise this is `False`
    type Eq: Boolean;
}

Most of the answer I've read is that this would not be possible, as it is unsound, but I'm failing to understand why. How could one break something with such a trait ?
The major argument I've seen is when lifetimes comes into play, things breaks down. I would be naively thinking that type equality also applies to lifetimes, meaning that &'a () == &'b () implies that 'a == 'b, and we can have lifetime equality as 'a == 'b <=> 'a: 'b && 'b: 'a.
I understand that TypeId can only exists for 'static types, as it can be be built at runtime where lifetimes don't exists. But type equality is also a compile time only thing, so how could it break Rust's soundness ?

How come you always hit the same barrier? As in: how is that a barrier to begin with? I don't recall a single time in my life when type comparison was relevant. This is especially true for Rust, which allows implementing new traits for already existing types (unlike most other languages).

Could you provide some links to people saying the things you claim they do (like the fact that type level not equals would be unsound)?

The only use case of a type inequality check I can think of is specialization, which isn't fully implemented in Rust yet. Once it is, you'll be able to implement a type inequality trait, but you won't need it anymore.

It appears that this question is asking for explanation of some specific argument about why this isn't possible, but without describing that argument ("Most of the answer I've read [...]" - which answers?). The simple answer for why it isn't possible is just that Rust (its maintainers) have chosen to not support it (or at least not at this time) likely for operational reasons. It it certainly possible to have a sound type system with some form of propositional type equality.

@freakish Most of the time, i end up needing a type level set as a primitive, which requires some level of type comparison to know if a type is already in that set or not. A simple example would be that MySet<usize, bool>: Set holds, but MySet<usize, usize>: Set does not.

Why can't MySet just be a trait?

@NaïmFavier Set is the trait, for all types that are sets. MySet is a type, that is a set, if it's two components are different.

That doesn't answer my question: what do you need MySet for?

@NaïmFavier I don't understand why this is relevant, and I don't think the "why do you want to build this anyway" is a proper response to "how can I do this". But one example, if you want it, is a type level database scheme, and database are a set of tables. Then, you can have a function such as query<Q: Query, D: Database>(db: &D) -> Q::Output, where you need a concrete type for D, just like you would need one for the set. There are more examples, and as I said I often end up needing such primitives, but this is not the point.

This is very relevant for the lifetime part. of the question It seems like it isn't impossible to make a not equal trait for lifetimes, but really difficult in the current rust compiler.

To make it clear: it is not unsound to make inequality constraints on type (T != U), although I heard this is very hard with the current trait solver (it may be easier with the next-gen trait solver). It is unsound to allow the user to switch code based on equality of types, in any form (specialization, complementary negative and positive bounds...)

@ChayimFriedman Why would it be unsound ? Out of curiosity, I can't think of an example. Is it unsound only if lifetimes are not considered, as you mentioned in your answer ?


But type equality is also a compile time only thing

Is it?
trait IsEq<T> {
    fn explode(&mut self, value: T);
}

// Imaginary syntax.
impl<T, U> IsEq<U> for T where T != U {
    fn explode(&mut self, value: T) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}

impl<T> IsEq<T> for T {
    fn explode(&mut self, value: T) {
        // Allowed, since `Self == T`.
        *self = value;
    }
}

If there is some way to implement the above trait for both T != U and T == U separately, then there must be a way to make the above code compile. But then explode() can trivially cause UB because monomorphization doesn't consider lifetimes:
let mut long: &String = ...;
{
    let short: String = ...;
    IsEq::explode(&mut long, &short);
}
// `long` refers `short` after it is dead, a use-after-free!

The reason this code will pass is that during codegen, when we decide which method to call, lifetimes are already erased and treated uniformly. So codegen see &'erased String for both types, which seems equal. We cannot make codegen lifetime-dependent, since this will mean an explosion of the monomorphizations we need to make - for every impl TypeWithLifetime, we will need to copy the code for every lifetime used.

This assumes that &'long String == &'short String to which begets the response "of course that can cause problems, but lifetimes are part of the type so if the lifetimes are different then the types are different!" Right now this doesn't really make sense as an answer without explaining more detail: like how monomorphization is relevant and why it couldn't be implemented in an expected way.

As mentioned in my post, and in the other comment, type equality for types with lifetimes would imply lifetime equality. So in your case, the explode call would be the one with an empty body, and no Ub at all !

@LucioleMaléfique But I explained why this is impossible - because monomorphization doesn't, and can't, consider lifetimes.

@ChayimFriedman using the definition of monomorphization from Wikipedia, I don't see why monomorphization can't consider lifetimes. It could start with choosing the implementation while considering the lifetimes, which in the case of different lifetime would be the empty implemetation, and then remove the lifetimes before monomorphizing. That means we don't generate infinite versions of the function, and don't choose the wrong implementation.

@trueequalsfalse Consider a very simple implementation impl<'a> T<'a> { ... }. If we monomorphize lifetimes (which is required for codegen to be able to differentiate in the above specialization), we need to copy the methods for each lifetime they are instantiated with, because they may eventually call a specialized method that depends on being able to make distinction between two different lifetimes. This is clearly very bad for code size.

@ChayimFriedman In theory, a smart compiler only needs to monomorphize the lifetimes that actually make a difference. Unfortunately this would probably be extremely difficult to implement. But in any case, for any function, there are only a finite amount of combinations for the lifetimes. The only thing that matters is the order of the sizes of the lifetimes and which of them are 'static. This would be slightly bad for code size, but not necessarily really bad (in practice only a few of the combinations would make a difference).

I believe the problem is that this requires trait impl specialization, which is a feature that is still to be implemented (which mentions the need for "Restrictions around lifetime dispatch (currently a soundness hole)").
You can implement the equal case
impl<T> IsEq<T> for T {
    type Eq = True;
}

But the unequal case is not expressible yet:
// FIXME: U must not be T
// error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `IsEq<_>`
impl<T, U> IsEq<T> for U { 
    type Eq = False;
}

